# Why is my DROP BOX download being blocked?

Tags: windows-xp, download, dropbox

I tried to download a **Dropbox** program and received the following message:

Cannot access the specific device, path or file. You may not have the appropriate permission to access the item.

What is preventing the download, and how can I complete the download?

Comment: Can you explain what "a Dropbox program" is? Are you referring to the [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) software itself?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're inadvertently trying to save the download in a location your account doesn't have access to (through NTFS permissions).

Try right-clicking on the download link and saving the file onto your desktop or My Documents.  Your account should definitely have access to those folders, unless your computer is managed by an IT department who has your workstation severely locked down.